# Excluding list items from query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a method which is working fine. I am trying to add some modification to the query and am not able to get through.

```
public List<ProductDetails> getQuestionsNotRelatedWithProduct(int iProductID, int iSpaceID)
        {

          var   oQuest    = (from s in db.Questionaires
                              join t in db._Product_UserQuestionaires
                              on s.Questionaire_ID equals t.Questionaire_ID
                              where !(from n in db.Product_UserQuestionaires
                                      join u in db.Products
                                      on n.Product_ID equals u._Product_ID
                                              where (u.Space_Type_ID == iSpaceID && u.Product_ID == iProductID)
                                      select n.Questionaire_ID).Contains(s.Questionaire_ID)
                              select new ProductDetails
                              {
                                  Question = s.Questionaire.ToString(),
                                  QuestionID = s.Questionaire_ID,
                              }).Distinct();
  return oQuest.ToList();

      }
```

i want to go like

```
public List<ProductDetails> getQuestionsNotRelatedWithProduct(int iProductID, int iSpaceID, IList questid)
{

//here i want to filter out/exclude the "IList questid" items from the query result
not getting how to do.

}
```

Can anyone please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the return statement in your original method to something like this

```
return oQuest.Where(i => !questid.Contains(i.QuestionID)).ToList();
```

Comment: i cut shortned everything and tried var oQuest = (from s in db.User_Questionaires where !(questid.Contains(s.User_Questionaire_ID .ToString())) select s); ITs giving error Method 'Boolean Contains(System.Object)' has no supported translation to SQL. How can i fix this? Please help